# Find value and replace in r

Tags: r

I need to find "9" in my dataframe and replace it with a value that is standing in another column.

For example my dataframe:

```
"1" "total_1_SNP20001" "mu" 1 1922 1369.25 1369.25 "." NA
"2" "total_1_SNP20001" "person" 3 1922 91.52 91.52 "a" NA
"3" "total_1_SNP20001" "barn.level.row" 17 1922 2.85 2.85 "A" NA
"4" "total_1_SNP20001" "9" NA 1 1922 1369.25 "1369.25" NA
"5" "total_1_SNP20002" "mu" 1 1921 1368.62 1346.47 "." NA
"6" "total_1_SNP20002" "person" 3 1921 91.48 91.41 "a" NA
"7" "total_1_SNP20002" "barn.level.row" 17 1921 2.85 2.85 "A" NA
"8" "total_1_SNP20002" "SNP20002" 1 1921 0.12 0.12 "A" 0.72
```

Here the `"9" NA 1922 1369.25 "1369.25" NA` needs to be replaced by `"SNP20001" 1 1921 0 0 "A" NA`. The part "SNP20001" needs to come from the column before (but minus the total_1_ part) and the rest are fixed values. How do I do that in R?

Comment: You can use this to replace by column, you just need to adjust it to your own code: `ir <- iris`, `ifelse(ir$Petal.Length == 1.4, ir$Sepal.Length[ir$Petal.Length == 1.4],"Test")` and then you can use the splitstr function to split the value of the first column.

Comment: If you post a part of your dataframe with `dput(dataframe)` I can help you further

Comment: The  `gsub` function can be used to replace values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Load data

```
rawdata <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text = '"1" "total_1_SNP20001" "mu" 1 1922 1369.25 1369.25 "." NA
"2" "total_1_SNP20001" "person" 3 1922 91.52 91.52 "a" NA
"3" "total_1_SNP20001" "barn.level.row" 17 1922 2.85 2.85 "A" NA
"4" "total_1_SNP20001" "9" NA 1 1922 1369.25 "1369.25" NA
"5" "total_1_SNP20002" "mu" 1 1921 1368.62 1346.47 "." NA
"6" "total_1_SNP20002" "person" 3 1921 91.48 91.41 "a" NA
"7" "total_1_SNP20002" "barn.level.row" 17 1921 2.85 2.85 "A" NA
"8" "total_1_SNP20002" "SNP20002" 1 1921 0.12 0.12 "A" 0.72')
```

## Edit column 3 only

If you only want to edit column 3, you could
Replace "9" in V3 by the value in the column before, V2

```
modified1 <- within(rawdata, V3 <- ifelse(V3 == "9", V2, V3))
# Remove  "total_1_" part
modified1 <- within(modified1, V3 <- gsub("total_1_", "", V3))
```

## Edit column 3 and other columns as  well

But you also wanted to add Add fixed values as well.
Then it's probably better to extract the lines you want to edit
and edit them all at once

```
editedlines <- subset(rawdata, V3 == "9")
editedlines <- within(editedlines, {
    V3 <- gsub("total_1_", "", V2)
    V4 <- 1
    V5 <- 1921
    V6 <- 0
    V7 <- 0
    V8 <- "A"
    V9 <- NA})
# Put editedlines back with the rest of the unmodified data
modified2 <- rbind(subset(rawdata, V3 != "9"),
                  editedlines)
# Arrange according to V1 if you prefer
modified2 <- modified2[order(modified2$V1),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
library(stringr)
df$V3 <- with(df, ifelse(V3==9, str_extract(V2, 'SNP[0-9]+'), V3))
df$V3
#[1] "mu"             "person"         "barn.level.row" "SNP20001"       "mu"             "person"         "barn.level.row" "SNP20002"
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `stringr` then,

```
df$V3 <- with(df, ifelse(V3==9, sub('.*_([_])*', '', V2), V3))
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = 1:8, V2 = c("total_1_SNP20001", "total_1_SNP20001", 
"total_1_SNP20001", "total_1_SNP20001", "total_1_SNP20002", "total_1_SNP20002", 
"total_1_SNP20002", "total_1_SNP20002"), V3 = c("mu", "person", 
"barn.level.row", "9", "mu", "person", "barn.level.row", 
"SNP20002"), V4 = c(1L, 3L, 17L, NA, 1L, 3L, 17L, 1L), V5 = c(1922L, 
1922L, 1922L, 1L, 1921L, 1921L, 1921L, 1921L), V6 = c(1369.25, 
91.52, 2.85, 1922, 1368.62, 91.48, 2.85, 0.12), V7 = c(1369.25, 
91.52, 2.85, 1369.25, 1346.47, 91.41, 2.85, 0.12), V8 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c(".", "1369.25", "a", 
"A"), class = "factor"), V9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.72
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", 
"V9"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

its a little messy and will work only on specified cases similar to data frame posted but its working

```
df[,3] <-  ifelse(df[,3] == "9", unlist(lapply(strsplit(df[,2],split = "_"), FUN = function(x) x[3])) , df[,3])
```

there is probably a much better way for doing it.